# Issue with uploading large images using ajax

Tags: ajax, image

I am using ajax to upload data including an image to my server side. When the image is below 1.35MB it works fine. However, for images larger then 1.35MB the other data is over written (e.g., when I

```
System.out.println("Level: " + request.getParameter("ssAccountLevel"));
```

It shows as null.

This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ResourceAddView",
    cache: false,
    data : {
        ssAccountLevel : sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountLevel'),
        ssAccountID : sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountID'),

        image : img2,
        imageType : imageType,
        resourceType: $("#resourceTypeAdd").val(),
        resourceName: $("#resourceNameAdd").val(),
        resourceDescription: $("#resourceDescriptionAdd").val(),
    },
})
.fail (function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    //alert(jqXHR.responseText);
    $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse13').text('Error adding Resource.');
})
.done(function(responseJson){
    $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse13').text('Resource added.');
    showResourceDataTable();
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by changing my ajax POST to json.

From:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "StoresAddView",
        cache: false,
        data : {
            ssAccountLevel : sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountLevel'),
            ssAccountID : sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountID'),
            ssGroupID : sessionStorage.getItem('ssGroupID'),

            itemNameAdd: $("#itemNameAdd").val(),
            itemDescriptionAdd : $("#itemDescriptionAdd").val(),
            ...
```

To:

```
var data =  {"ssAccountLevel" : sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountLevel'),
                "ssAccountID" : sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccountID'),
                "ssGroupID" : sessionStorage.getItem('ssGroupID'),
                "itemNameAdd" : $("#itemNameAdd").val(),
                "itemDescriptionAdd" : $("#itemDescriptionAdd").val(),
                ...}
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "StoresAddView",
                cache: false,
                contentType: "application/json",
                processData: false,
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
            })
```

I do not know why this worked. Any explanation would be greatly received as to why the original code worked for smaller uploads only.

Kind regards,

Glyn